# Jquery mobile File control not working in device

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, file-upload, android-webview

I am using default `File` control in jquery mobile 1.2.0. Its working fine in browser. But its not working in device. I tried with Samsung Galaxy Tab 2.

The control html looks like:

```
<div id="divattachImg" data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="attachImg">Attach Image (Optional):</label>
    <input type="file" name="attachImg" id="attachImg" value="" maxlength="45">
</div>
```

When I click on the control in device, it doesn't do anything. Its like, click never happened.
Am I doing something wrong here or is this problem with jqm? If so, can you suggest any work around for this?

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S: I am using this in android webview. (Not phonegap.)

Comment: Android version? Browser or Phonegap app?

Comment: Android version @Gajotres

Comment: What android version is on your Galaxy Tab?

Comment: ICS @Gajotres . Android 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Gajotres had answered on my question, but as it didn't work, he removed that answer.
But he had provided a [link](http://m0s-programming.blogspot.in/2011/02/file-upload-in-through-webview-on.html) in his answer which helped me solving my problem. I am answering my question in the hope that it helps someone else in future.

In that tutorial, the [last comment](http://m0s-programming.blogspot.in/2011/02/file-upload-in-through-webview-on.html?showComment=1345308705417#c4277804208730525915) includes a [working example](http://opensourcesoftwareandme.blogspot.in/2012/08/attaching-file-in-cordova-uploading-it.html#.UW-3g6JHJDQ). [That example](https://github.com/claudemamo/file-attach-cordova-upload-jqm/blob/master/src/main/java/org/opensourcesoftwareandme/FileAttachmentActivity.java) states that you need to use method with different arguments for both <3.x and >3.x. I used that and it worked.

So finally solution will be like:

```
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;

public class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {

            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");
            System.out.println("starting act for result");
            MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Browser"),
                    FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }

        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                String acceptType) {
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");

            MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose type of attachment"),
                    FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
        }
    }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
            if (null == mUploadMessage)
                return;
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null
                    : intent.getData();
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps someone in future.